# Circular Dependency Warnings using NgRx with Interceptor

Tags: angular, ngrx, interceptor, circular-dependency, ngrx-store

I am adding a dispatch in my interceptor to check if the users token expired to log them out, but for some reason I am getting quite a few warnings about Circular dependency.

```js
// Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
// RxJS
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
// import { debug } from 'util';
// NGRX
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
// State
import { AppState } from '../../../../core/reducers';
import { Logout } from '../../../../core/auth/';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}
    // intercept request and add token
    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
        // modify request
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`
            }
        });
        // console.log('----request----');
        // console.log(request);
        // console.log('--- end of request---');

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(
                event => {

                     if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        // console.log('all looks good');
                        // http response status code
                         console.log(event.status);
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    // http response status code
                    // console.log('----response----');
                    // console.error('status code:');
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
                    // console.error(error.status);
                    console.error(error.error.error);
                    if (error.error.error !== undefined && error.error.error.includes('Expired Token')) {
                        alert('You have been logged out due to signing in from another');
                        this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
                    }
                    // console.log('--- end of response---');
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

The code works as it should, but I didn't know if I should be aware of these issues. I am using the exact same structure on my Logout Component and no issues there. I'm assuming because it's a service?

// auth.effect.ts

```js
// Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
// RxJS
import { filter, mergeMap, tap, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { defer, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
// NGRX
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action, select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
// Auth actions
import { AuthActionTypes, Login, Logout, Register, UserLoaded, UserRequested } from '../_actions/auth.actions';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/index';
import { AppState } from '../../reducers';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment.prod';
import { isUserLoaded } from '../_selectors/auth.selectors';

@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {

    @Effect({dispatch: false})
    logout$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<Logout>(AuthActionTypes.Logout),
        tap(() => {
            localStorage.removeItem(environment.authToken);
            this.router.navigate(['/auth/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: this.returnUrl}});
        })
    );

    private returnUrl: string;

    constructor(private actions$: Actions,
        private router: Router,
        private auth: AuthService,
        private store: Store<AppState>) {

        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.returnUrl = event.url;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```js
//auth.reducer.ts

// Actions
import { AuthActions, AuthActionTypes } from '../_actions/auth.actions';
// Models
import { User } from '../_models/user.model';

export interface AuthState {
    loggedIn: boolean;
    authToken: string;
    user: User;
    isUserLoaded: boolean;
}

export const initialAuthState: AuthState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    authToken: undefined,
    user: undefined,
    isUserLoaded: false
};

export function authReducer(state = initialAuthState, action: AuthActions): AuthState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.Logout:
            return initialAuthState;


        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```js
//auth.actions.ts

import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from '../_models/user.model';

export enum AuthActionTypes {
    Logout = '[Logout] Action'
}

export class Logout implements Action {
    readonly type = AuthActionTypes.Logout;
}


export type AuthActions = Logout;
```

```js
// ../core/reducers/index.ts

// NGRX
import { ActionReducerMap, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';
import { routerReducer } from '@ngrx/router-store';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment.prod';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
export interface AppState { }

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = { router: routerReducer };

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<AppState>[] = !environment.production ? [storeFreeze] : [];
```

Comment: I have the same issue that i resolved plz can you show me you AppState and Logout

Comment: @A.khalifa I've added the additional files

Comment: Have you found an answer for your problem yet?